# Maps of modules over a ring in terms of ring actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

An abelian group $M$ can be given a structure of $A$-module for a commutative ring $A$ with $1$ either by defining an operation $A \times M \to M$ and checking that a handful of axioms hold, or more concisely by giving a ring homomorphism $A \to \mathrm{End}_\mathrm{Grp}(M)$. Given two A-modules $M$ and $M'$, and their corresponding homomorphisms $f : A \to \mathrm{End}_\mathrm{Grp}(M)$ and $f': A \to \mathrm{End}_\mathrm{Grp}(M')$, is there a way to express the property for a map $M \to M'$ to be $A$-linear involving $f$ and $f'$?

I had hoped that those maps $M \to M'$ which are $A$-linear might correspond to homomorphisms $\mathrm{End}_\mathrm{Grp}(M) \to \mathrm{End}_\mathrm{Grp}(M')$ of $A$-algebras but I was not able to fill in the details.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: The maps $f$ and $f'$ determine the module structures on $M$ and $M'$, so you want that homomorphism from $M$ to $M'$ to be compatible with them. What ways are there to combine $f$ and $f'$ with a map from $\mathrm{End}_{\text{Grp}}(M)$ to $\mathrm{End}_{\text{Grp}}(M')$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
Let $\varphi\colon M\rightarrow M'$ be a homomorphism of abelian groups. Then $\varphi$ is $A$-linear if and only if the following diagram commutes:
$$
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> {\rm End}(M)\\
@V{f'}VV & @VV{\varphi_*}V\\
{\rm End}(M') @>>{\varphi^*}> {\rm Hom}(M,M')
\end{CD}
$$
where $\varphi_*(g) = \varphi\circ g$ for $g\in {\rm End}(M)$ and $\varphi^*(g) = g\circ\varphi$ for $g\in {\rm End}(M')$.

Comment: Would you care to comment on your choice of using $\varphi^*$
and $\varphi_*$ in this order and not the other way around? Does this follow a convention of some sort? I seem to remember that in other contexts (e.g., the image of a map $\varphi$ under a covariant functor), people might choose notations in such a way that $\varphi_*(g)$ would expand to $\varphi \circ g$.

Comment: You are right, I changed the notation. I didn't think about it thoroughly.